# Extract 2D sub-array (without using Matrix)

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

In Ruby, given an array-of-arrays representing a 2D grid of numbers, how would you extract a specific sub-2D array?

```
a = [[0, 3, 1, 5, 5],
     [4, 6, 8, 3, 5],
     [7, 1, 4, 0, 8],
     [0, 8, 8, 7, 4],
     [7, 2, 4, 5, 4]]

require 'pp'
pp sub_array(a,1..4,2..4)
#=> [[8, 3, 5],
#=>  [4, 0, 8],
#=>  [8, 7, 4],
#=>  [4, 5, 4]]
```

This is 'easy' to do using the [`Matrix`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) library:

```
m = Matrix[*a]
p m.minor(1..4,2..4).to_a
#=> [[8, 3, 5], [4, 0, 8], [8, 7, 4], [4, 5, 4]]
```

However, I feel certain that there's an elegant way to do this without using the Matrix, perhaps involving zip or transpose :)

*I'm including the words "two-dimensional" here for search hits.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def sub_array(xs, rows, columns)
  xs[rows].map { |row| row[columns] }
end

sub_array(a, 1..4, 2..4)
#=> [[8, 3, 5], [4, 0, 8], [8, 7, 4], [4, 5, 4]]
```

Comment: Silly me. Or even `xs[rows].map{ |row| row[columns] }`

Comment: Lovely! I forgot about `values_at`.

Comment: changed `values_at` to `[]`, `Array#[]` is smarter than I thought :-)

Comment: Probably not as efficient, but the variant `xs[rows].transpose[columns].transpose` also works.